# Is there a well working implementation of wavenet publicly available?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm currently interested in doing a project based on wavenet, but I haven't found any implementation, that even resembles something like Google Deepmind advertises [here](https://deepmind.com/blog/article/wavenet-generative-model-raw-audio). The most popular [implementation](https://github.com/ibab/tensorflow-wavenet) links to [this example output](https://soundcloud.com/user-731806733/tensorflow-wavenet-500-msec-88k-train-steps) which isn't even remotely close Deepminds [examples](https://storage.googleapis.com/deepmind-media/research/WaveNet/Speaker%201/speaker-1.wav) of "randomly" generated speech.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an issue in the github about Speech Generation that might answer your question:
https://github.com/ibab/tensorflow-wavenet/issues/47

They manage to generate random speech, for example:

https://soundcloud.com/user-952268654/wavenet-28k-steps-of-100k-samples

https://soundcloud.com/user-731806733/generated-larger-1

Otherwise, I didn't found any code that directly generate random speech, but an implementation in Keras seems to be easier to use:

https://github.com/basveeling/wavenet